# SharePoint 2010 Audit/Web analytics, how to see what user accessed what site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In the Web Analytics report  I can see how many visitors visited a site, number of page views and so on. I can't see exactly who viewed what page though. I also had a look at the Audit Settings but it only logs who accessed a file, edited a document, checked out, deleted document and a a few more options, not who visited what site.

Where should I start looking for this kind of report?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

John,
Please look at this [Sharepoint HitCounter Webpart](http://www.fivenumber.com/sharepoint-hit-counter-web-part/)

this might be useful for you..